# how to loop gradient directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

nedd to loop gradient directions of an element

in the code below **only the first click** works properly

btw I suppose there is a shorter way to do the same

```js
var targ = $('#targ');
$('button').on('click', function(){
 var a = targ.css('background-image');
 console.log(a);
 if(~a.indexOf('to right,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('right', 'right bottom'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to right bottom,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('right bottom', 'bottom'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to bottom,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('bottom', 'bottom left'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to bottom left,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('bottom left', 'left'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to left,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('left', 'left top'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to left top,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('left top', 'top'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to top,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('top', 'top right'));}
 else if(~a.indexOf('to top right,')){targ.css('background-image', a.replace('top right', 'right'));}
 console.log(targ.css('background-image'));
});
```

```css
#targ{height:45px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div id='targ' style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(109, 213, 237), rgb(33, 147, 176))"></div>
```

Comment: `a.replace('right', 'right bottom')` this piece needs to be changed. Either change to 'right' or to 'to right bottom'

Comment: @Gerard - can't see your point. this is the only line which works properly. why to change it?

Comment: `to bottom` is the default and  gets serialized to the empty string by getComputedStyle which is returned by $.css. Just use a state machine rather than relying on getComputedStyles

Comment: @Kaiido, I see now the reason, thanks, but what you mean by `a state machine`, how to avoid serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to bottom` is the default and  gets serialized to the empty string by `getComputedStyle` which is used by `$.css()`.

```js
console.log( getComputedStyle( document.getElementById('target') )
  .getPropertyValue('background-image')
); // linear-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 255))
```

```css
#target {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Just use a state machine rather than relying on `getComputedStyle`.
And if you need to handle variable colors, then store these colors as *data-attributes* on your elements.

```js
var targ = $('#targ');
var vals = [
    "right",
    "right bottom",
    "bottom",
    "bottom left",
    "left",
    "left top",
    "top",
    "top right"
  ];
var state = 0;

$('button').on('click', function() {
  state = (state + 1) % vals.length;
  var col_1 = targ.attr('data-color-1');
  var col_2 = targ.attr('data-color-2');
  targ.css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(to '+ vals[ state ] + ',' + col_1 + ',' + col_2 + ')');
});
```

```css
#targ{height:45px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div id='targ' data-color-1="#6dd5ed" data-color-2="#2193b0" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #6dd5ed, #2193b0)"></div>
```

Comment: hmm, `rgb(109, 213, 237), rgb(33, 147, 176)` are also variables, on another target they are different

Comment: @qadenza store it somewhere else, for instance in `data-` attributes. For each of your elements you add `data-color-1="rgb(...)" data-color-2="rgb(...)"` and then you grab these data-attributes in the js code.

Comment: believe me, I tried that already, but it is very hard, if not impossible te extract that values from a string. i.e. that values are not mine, they;re given by user.. I think the only way is to split the string somehow and then concatenate it later

Comment: Or make the proper UI so that your users give you data in a format you can control?